# grails table collation latin_swedish_ci although db collation is utf8_general_ci

Tags: mysql, database, grails, encoding, collation

I created a database for my grails project with default collation utf8_general_ci but now I found out that grails created all tables with latin_swedish_ci.

Why is that and how can I force grails to use utf8?

In other topics I found that I need to add some parameters at the db connection string but I already did that. This is my datasource:

```
dataSource {
    dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"
    driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    username = "root"
    password = ""
    url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xxx?autoReconnect=true&useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8"
}
```

Comment: Maybe something has any ideas about this problem? We have the same issue 4 years later.

Answer (score 1):

My datasource looks exactly the same and my table's collations are set to 'utf8_general_ci' . My impression is that this needs to be configured in the database server itself, either generally or per database.

The forme would involve adding the following to your my.cnf file:

```
[mysqld]
character-set-server=utf8
collation-server=utf8_general_ci
```

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-applications.html for more info.

I usually do the latter one though. I use the following syntax to create my databases:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS $DB_NAME;
CREATE DATABASE $DB_NAME DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```